# Adding jQuery noConflict

Tags: jquery

I added this code in `<head>` tag (for correct display in ie, but adding respond.min.js work breaks other scripts on the page).

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

but after that some other scripts on the page stopped working.
If I add to these scripts jQuery noConflict, it can help solve the problem of compatibility with other scripts? how to do it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ try searching...

Comment: I have read it, but I don't understand how to it add to my scripts ;(

Comment: Are you sure if it is a JQuery conflict issue? Did you put the css files just before respond.min.js?

Comment: I have problem not with css, I have problem with other scripts http://i.imgur.com/fx01445.png

Comment: Ok your are getting a 404 error, please check the script paths, it seems browser can not find the script.

Comment: It works properly if I do not add scripts in `head` (from question above)